# Getting original request URL from Express response

Tags: express

Is there an elegant way of retrieving the original request URL from the Express `response` object?

Using the `request` object, I can do something like:

```
getFullUrl(req) {
    return url.format({
        host: environment.getHost(req),
        pathname: req.originalUrl,
        protocol: req.protocol
    });
}
```

I was wondering if I could do something similar with the `response`? Looks like the `href` property gives me what I need but wanted to get some more thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `res.req` to get the `request` object from the `response` object so you can then use the same logic you were already using on the `request` object.

I can't find anywhere that this is documented, but you can see it in `console.log()` or in the debugger - it's there.  So, tread carefully as there may be no guarantee that this never changes.

Both `res.req` and `req.res` appear to be Express-specific additions to the request and response objects.  You can see them assigned [here in the source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/middleware/init.js#L28) in a default early middleware handler Express adds:

```
/**
 * Initialization middleware, exposing the
 * request and response to each other, as well
 * as defaulting the X-Powered-By header field.
 *
 * @param {Function} app
 * @return {Function}
 * @api private
 */

exports.init = function(app){
  return function expressInit(req, res, next){
    if (app.enabled('x-powered-by')) res.setHeader('X-Powered-By', 'Express');
    req.res = res;
    res.req = req;
    req.next = next;

    setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
    setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)

    res.locals = res.locals || Object.create(null);

    next();
  };
};
```

While they don't appear to be documented, the internals of Express rely on them all over the place.  Just looking at the [`response.js` file from the Express repository](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L993), there are all sorts of uses of `res.req` internally in Express.  So, if they were to remove it in the future, they'd have to change a lot of their own code to do so.  I'd say it seems relatively safe to use.

Comment: Just to clarify for myself, the https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage class does not specify a Request property for me to use officially, so I should not rely on it always being there correct?

Comment: @User5842 - Correct.  It appears to be an Express-specific property.  See the comments I added to my answer and